# Try to get key values recursively from JSON in Angular 5

Tags: json, typescript, key, angular5

I want to retrieve **all** the *key values* from a JSON file. For example in :

```
{
 "total_count": 6,
 "incomplete_results": false,
 "items": [
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Samhot/GenIHM/issues/6",
    "id": 293237635,
    "number": 6,
    "title": "Rechercher des documents",
    "user": {
      "login": "Samhot",
      "id": 7148311
 ]
}
```

I would like to get :
`["total_count", "incomplete_results", "items", "url", "url", "number", "title", "user", "login", "id"]`

I have a function which return the content of my JSON in an observable :

```
  getConfig(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.myURL);
  }
```

After that the data are reformated with `.map` to get only the keys with the `Object.keys()` function :

```
  merge()
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.getConfig();
    }),
    map(data => {
      return Object.keys(data.items[0]);
      }
    )
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.dispo = data;
  });
```

My problem is that i get only the keys that are in the level of the JSON I told 
(**data.items[0]**) and not the ascendants or the descendants.

Of course I can create multiple requests but it asks to know in advance the structure of the JSON, what I want is to make it **generic** ...

How can I do to have an array with with all of my keys regardless of the structure of the JSON ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do a recursive function like:

```js
function getDeepKeys(obj) {
  
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);

  const childKeys = keys
    .map(key => obj[key])
    .map(
      value =>
        Array.isArray(value)
          ? getDeepKeys(value[0])
          : typeof value === "object"
            ? getDeepKeys(value)
            : []
    )
    .reduce((acc, keys) => [...acc, ...keys], []);
  return [...keys, ...childKeys];
}

const obj = {
  total_count: 6,
  incomplete_results: false,
  items: [
    {
      url: "https://api.github.com/repos/Samhot/GenIHM/issues/6",
      id: 293237635,
      number: 6,
      title: "Rechercher des documents",
      user: {
        login: "Samhot",
        id: 7148311
      }
    },
    {
      url: "https://api.github.com/repos/Samhot/GenIHM/issues/6",
      id: 293237635,
      number: 6,
      title: "Rechercher des documents",
      user: {
        login: "Samhot",
        id: 7148311
      }
    }
  ]
};

console.log(getDeepKeys(obj));
```

Which then you would use like `map(getDeepKeys)`. Note that this function assumes all the items in your array have the same schema.

Comment: Thank you J. Pichardo but your solution doesn't return the "user" keys...
`["total_count", "incomplete_results", "items", "url", "number", "title", "user"]`
And if i want all the keys i have to add `...Object.keys(data.items[0].user)` but it's not generic, it will only works on this JSON

Comment: @samhot sorry I totally missed those properties in the example, I've updated the question.

Comment: Thank you again but this time it only returns the keys in "user" (`["login", "id"]`) ... I think if we could change `return [...Object.keys(obj), ...childKeys];` to add the "parentKeys" it would works no ?

Comment: Well yeah, I did that as a quick experiment, but I do have a running example for thay funcion. I'll try and post it asap